# Is there an easier way to refer to Javascript class methods from within the class?

Tags: javascript, class, this

I come from a non-javascript coding background and one of the things that I am used to doing is encapsulating code in a class.

So I have a class file and it works but the constant reference to `this.` is lacks a certain *elegance* that makes me think that I am doing things the wrong way. Especially when I try to reference `this.` from within a "level" of code in a method and I have to carry the reference in a local variable to make it work.

So here is an example of what I have

```js
class catalogue {

    constructor () {

        this.currentDoc = null;
        this.dataDirectory = "data/";

    }
    
    loadJSON(filepath) {
        // there is actual code in the real class
    }
    
    loadHTML(filePath) {
        // there is actual code in the real class
    }
    
    loadExternalData() {

        let filePath = `${this.dataDirectory}${this.currentDoc.filepath}`;
        let dataIsJson = this.currentDoc.filepath.indexOf('.json') != -1;

        let me = this; // this again :-(
        
        if (dataIsJson) {
            me.loadJSON(filePath);
        } else {
            me.loadHTML(filePath);
        }

    }
    
}
```

The `loadExternalData()` method is called from the code that creates an instance of the class. It then determines how to load the data that it required and it calls various methods depending on the type of data.

Back in the 'old days' I would have stored a reference to the class as a property of the class and then used that to call methods. The main problem is that, as we know, `this.` is contextual and as soon as you use a conditional or anything similar the context, for some bizarre reason, changes and `this.` is not useful to my class any more.

So all of this makes me think that I am not doing things in a *Javascripty* fashion.

Is there an easier way to refer to methods and properties without using `this.` or do I need to look at reworking the code?

Comment: Does the code as posted actually fail without the `let me = this;` line? Because at a first glance what you're written would work fine if you just said `this.loadJson(...)`. The only point where the context can change is at a function call boundary. Granted, these boundaries can happen more often in JS than other languages (event handlers, for example.) Is this really a representative example of your problem? Since at first glance it doesn't appear to be .

Comment: The code works. This is just sample code I pulled out because the actual code is littered with comments

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an acceptable answer to a question that contains both "I come from a different language" and "is there an easier way [to make this look like the language I am used to]". This is the case here too - the language specification requires the use of the `this` keyword as you've written it. CertainPerformance has provided the modern solution to the problem you describe - it just doesn't "make it easier".

Comment: "*Back in the 'old days' I would have stored a reference to the class as a property of the class and then used that to call methods.*" - uh, no? "*as we know, `this` is contextual and as soon as you use a conditional or anything similar the context, for some bizarre reason, changes*" - no, [absolutely not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)?!

Comment: >  no, absolutely not?!

Not sure what part of that quote you are referring to @Bergi but I am reading through the Doc page again.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I was hoping that I made it clear that I am more than willing to be told that what I am doing is not the correct way to do things. I just wanted to explain the context for how I am structuring the code. 

Part of the reason for this question was the feeling that I must be doing something wrong as I was working against what appeared to be the languages apparent way of doing things.

Comment: @Zac - Right, you haven't done anything wrong. In a practical sense there are not _really_ too many situations that make `this` wacky - but, every one of them are initiated by us programmers. The language doesn't switch things around just because it wants to - it does it because we tell it too. So I suppose the challenge is gaining a better understanding of how the language works in that regard. I realize you get that too.

Comment: @Zac The `this` value does not change in conditionals or other forms of control flow structures, and not for bizarre reasons either.

Comment: @Bergi it certainly isn't arbitrary and capricious as I may be making it out. Coming from outside the JS world it does seem a touch odd though. I suspect that the classes and other ES6 features are in a flux state as they evolve. Currently they are very helpful and have made this current project much cleaner.

Comment: "The this value does not change in conditionals or other forms of control flow structures" @Bergi I believe the issue I am running into is using this. in strict mode. All the code is in a class as I mentioned and that automatically sets strict mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is perfectly normal and common. If what you're worried about it:

> The main problem is that, as we know, this. is contextual and as soon as you use a conditional or anything similar the context, for some bizarre reason, changes and this. is not useful to my class any more.

A very simple tweak is to use arrow function class fields instead, so that `this` will always refer to the instance, without having to worry about a changing calling context.

```
class catalogue {
    constructor () {

        this.currentDoc = null;
        this.dataDirectory = "data/";
    }
    loadJSON = (filepath) => {
        // there is actual code in the real class
    }
    loadHTML = (filePath) => {
        // there is actual code in the real class
    }
    loadExternalData = () =>  {
        let filePath = `${this.dataDirectory}${this.currentDoc.filepath}`;
        let dataIsJson = this.currentDoc.filepath.indexOf('.json') != -1;
        if (dataIsJson) {
            this.loadJSON(filePath);
        } else {
            this.loadHTML(filePath);
        }

    }
    
}
```

> Is there an easier way to refer to methods and properties without using this

Not particularly, though I suppose if the functions are bound to `this` properly, you could also extract them into standalone variables first, maybe in the first line of the function. IMO it's not an improvement, but YMMV. Eg

```
    loadExternalData() {
        let filePath = `${this.dataDirectory}${this.currentDoc.filepath}`;
        let dataIsJson = this.currentDoc.filepath.indexOf('.json') != -1;
```

could change to

```
    loadExternalData() {
        const { dataDirectory, currentDoc } = this;
        let filePath = `${dataDirectory}${currentDoc.filepath}`;
        let dataIsJson = currentDoc.filepath.indexOf('.json') != -1;
```

Could also probably change the last line to

```
const dataIsJson = currentDoc.filePath.endsWith('.json');
```

to be precise.

Comment: I don't see any reason to drop the methods and add class fields with arrow functions here.

Comment: OP was worried about sometimes accidentally calling the methods with the wrong calling context, resulting in problems due to `this` referring to undesirable - using arrow functions instead will take that worry away.

Comment: I'd argue that is the fault of the caller, though. And we haven't even see that code. Using arrow functions for everything, just out of caution, is not a good practice.

Comment: The entire class is 278 lines of code so I thought it was better not to post it :-) 

I'm not worried about accidentally calling methods with the wrong context, just that the way I am structuring the class makes me think that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Zac Well, the `let me = this` is unnecessary (only time you'd have needed something like that is if using a `function` callback inside and weren't allowed to use arrow function). And you said *The main problem is that, as we know*, which seemed to imply that the `this` changing when not intended was a big part of what you were uncertain about.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. I'll give those suggestions a try this evening and see how they work.

Comment: Actually I added the me. reference because I was getting errors.

Comment: So... I don't know how I was getting the errors in the first place but as @Bergi mentions, except where I am calling back to the class from in an async function call I have been able to remove all of the `let me =` code and `me.` references. It was clearly causing a problem earlier. I think I am going to have to go back and see if I can replicate what was causing the errors in the first place. **Big thanks** to everyone for the comments and links to reference material